# Dot notation access to MongoDB Query results (BsonDocuments) in C#

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, serialization, mongodb-.net-driver

How can I access the MongoCursor attributes in C#.

I have the following line of code:

```
MongoCursor results = collection.Find(searchQuery).SetLimit(10).SetFields(
Fields.Include("name1","name", "_id"));
```

MongoDB returns an array, each one with two attributes: name and name1. In the results View in the debugger,, I can see an array, each item in the array contains a `MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument`.

I want to have a dot notation access to the attributes of each BsonDocument in the Array. How can I achieve this.?

Comment: `results` will hold 10 documents, each with the `name1`, `name` and `_id` attributes. Are you asking how to get these attributes' values?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not explaining myself correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get values out of a `BsonDocument` you can use the `GetValue`/`TryGetValue` methods or the indexer:

```
foreach (var document in results)
{
    var name1 = document.GetValue("name1");
    var name = document["name"];
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Came across this issue when I had to work with raw BsonDocuments.  This solution does allow you to use dot notation.

Not fully tested or anything, but may be useful.

```
void Main()
{
    var example = new BsonDocument{
        { "customer", new BsonDocument { { "email" , "homerjay@simpsons.com" } }}
    };

    var email = example.GetPath("customer.email").AsString;

    Console.WriteLine(email);
}

public static class MongoDbHelper
{
    public static BsonValue GetPath(this BsonValue bson, string path)
    {
        if (bson.BsonType != BsonType.Document)
        {
            throw new Exception("Not a doc");
        }

        var doc = bson.AsBsonDocument;

        var tokens = path.Split(".".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        if (tokens.Length == 0 )
        {
            return doc;
        }

        if (!doc.Contains(tokens[0]))
        {
            return BsonNull.Value;
        }

        if (tokens.Length > 1)
        {
            return GetPath(doc[tokens[0]], tokens[1]);
        } 

        return doc[tokens[0]];
    }
}
```

Comment: This above code has a bug.  I tried to edit it to fix it, but it was rejected as being a comment to the author for some reason.  The code above only works when the given path is less than 2 deep.  To fix the bug, in the line for the path.Split, add the argument to limit the count to 2 (`var tokens = path.Split(new [] {'.'}, 2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`).  This way `tokens[1]` contains the rest of the path and will work for paths of any depth ( `doc.GetPath("o.idIndex.ns");`)